# Mysql Using Result of Subquery in Main Query

Tags: mysql

Basically, what I want to do is to get all children in another table within a certain birth year. So I have two tables. Let's say it's a school table

**School**

```
school_id
child_id
```

**Children**

```
child_id
birth_year
name
etc
```

My first attempt is to use subquery, which is something like this

```
SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM school LEFT JOIN children ON school.child_id = children.child_id) as total FROM school LEFT JOIN children ON school.child_id = children.child_id GROUP BY birth_year
```

The problem with this query is the subquery will run all throughout the records, so if I have 1000 records, I think the query (and the subquery) will run 1000 times before grouping by birth_year, which is slow, it's almost 3-5 seconds for 500 sample data.

So to optimize it, I'm doing this.

**Recursive Query Using PHP**

First, get the distinct birth year of ALL children who are in school. So I'm gonna query something like

```
SELECT birth_year FROM school LEFT JOIN children ON school.child_id = children.child_id
```

It will return data like

```
birth_year
==========
2009
2010
2011
```

Which I'm gonna use in another query in PHP (let's say I store the result in $row variable)

```
foreach ($row as $r){
    $new_array[] = count($this->db->get_child_data($r->birth_year)); //this is pseudocode only, to get the number of children data who have birth_year of 2009-2011
}
```

Though it will run additional three queries, this is really fast as the count is simple. It only takes less than 0.5 seconds for 500 sample data.

However, I'm wondering if there's any way of optimizing it? Or better, is there a way to do it in a single query with similar performance?

I'm trying to do this, but it ends up super slow and crashes my WAMP.

```
SELECT * FROM children WHERE birth_year IN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT birth_year) FROM school LEFT JOIN children ON school.child_id = children.child_id )
```

The subquery

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT birth_year) FROM school LEFT JOIN children ON school.child_id = children.child_id
```

when run separately correctly and quickly returns

```
2009,2010,2011
```

And when I query

```
SELECT * FROM children WHERE birth_year IN (2009,2010,2011)
```

It also works fast , so I'm quite confused why when I join both queries, it is slow to the point to crash my WAMP.

Sorry for the long post and thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that using subqueries in the `IN` or `SELECT` clauses often causes them to be run again for each row in the outer query.  To avoid this, try joining to the subquery.  This should result in the subquery being run only once, and cached.

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM children c, (SELECT birth_year FROM school LEFT JOIN children ON school.child_id = children.child_id GROUP BY birth_year) b
WHERE c.birth_year = b.birth_year
```

That said, it looks like you're just getting **every child** in any school anyway, so a simpler JOIN might also give you the same result.

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM children c, school s
WHERE c.child_id = s.child_id
```

If you just want to get the count of kids in each school, for each birth_year

```
SELECT count(c.child_id), s.* 
FROM school s 
LEFT JOIN children c ON c.child_id = s.child_id
GROUP BY s.school_id, c.birth_year
```

Comment: actually I tried using subquery, see my first attempt, as I want to get the total of the children each year. The bottleneck seems like the count subquery though...

Comment: The key here is the location of the subquery.  I have to say though, it's not exactly clear what your end goal is.

Comment: i think i'd go with recursive PHP query, it's blazing fast, i'm talking about 4 seconds (subqueries) vs 0.2 second (recursive PHP). You're right, my end goal is to get total of children in school each year, the easiest way to do it is recursive query I guess as it lets PHP do the hard work

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to get the number of children in a birth year

```
SELECT COUNT (c.child_id) FROM child c INNER JOIN school s ON (c.child_id = s.child_id) GROUP BY birthyear
```

If you need additional filters then you can add a where clause for the years that you want

Comment: that's what I want to do as in my first attempt : SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM school LEFT JOIN children ON school.child_id = children.child_id) as total FROM school LEFT JOIN children ON school.child_id = children.child_id GROUP BY birth_year which is slow. I think the joining of  school with children in the subquery is necessary to give more accurate result ( so the children which are not in school are not included)